# How can I insert non-consecutive values from a list into specific keys of a dictionary with conditions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Python - Add list values to dictionary but ensure they are not consecutive

Hello. I've got a list, say :

`l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`

I've also got a dictionary with 3 keys with empty lists, say :

```
sample = {
    "A": [],
    "B": [],
    "C": [],
}
```

I need to insert the values of the list into the values of the dictionary, but ensure that each key only has 4 values, and they cannot be consecutive.

For example, this would be correct, since each key has 4 values and none of them are consecutive :

```
sample = {
    "A": [1, 3, 5, 7],
    "B": [2, 10, 12, 8],
    "C": [4, 11, 9, 6],
}
```

The values can be random (that is, they need not be in ascending/descending order), but they have to be from the list. Can someone please help me on this?

This is what I've got so far. It inserts the values into the list, but the values are all consecutive.

```
`overs = []

# Creates a list with values from 1 to 12
for i in range(1, 13):
    overs.append(i)

print(overs)

players = {"A": [], "B": [], "C": []}


# Creates a dictionary where the values of the list are inserted into the values of the dictionary

for player in players:
    for i in range(1, 13):
        try:
            if len(players[player]) < 4:
                players[player].append(overs[0])
                overs.pop(0)

        except IndexError:
            break


print(players)`
```

```
Output : 

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
{'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'C': [9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

Comment: I know you said random was ok, but is it important that any of this is random?

Comment: @JonSG no, I just meant they don't have to be ascending/descending, but even if they are, it's not a problem. They just can't be consecutive, that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dictionary with 3 key and 4 not consecutive values

```py
# Creates a list with values from 1 to 12
overs = list(range(1, 13))
print(overs)

# Creates a dictionary where the values of the list are inserted into the values of the dictionary
players = {"A": [], "B": [], "C": []}
for player in players:
    prev_value = None  # Store the previous value for each player
    while len(players[player]) < 4 and overs:  # Stop when the list is empty or the player's list has 4 elements
        current_value = overs.pop(0)  # Take the first value from the list
        if prev_value is not None and abs(current_value - prev_value) == 1:  # Check for consecutive values
            overs.append(current_value)  # Reinsert the consecutive value back to the list
        else:
            players[player].append(current_value)
            prev_value = current_value

print(players)
```

Answer (score 2):

Before doing something more sophisticated, I would simply put the first item in the first bucket and the next in the next using the modulo operator to wrap around.

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
sample = {"A": [], "B": [], "C": []}
values = list(sample.values())
values_len = len(values)

for index, item in enumerate(l):
    values[index % values_len].append(item)

print(sample)
```

That will give you:

```
{'A': [1, 4, 7, 10], 'B': [2, 5, 8, 11], 'C': [3, 6, 9, 12]}
```

(every time)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the distribution to be more random, you could also try this:

```py
import random

sample = {
    "A": [],
    "B": [],
    "C": [],
}

l = [i+1 for i in range(12)]
samples = len(sample)

for i in range(0, len(l), samples):           # iterate over sample in steps of 3 (number of keys)
    order = random.sample(list(sample.keys()), samples)  # shuffle order in which keys appear
    for key, item in zip(order, l[i:i+samples]):         # add numbers sequentially to shuffled keys
        sample[key].append(item)
        
print(sample)
```

Sample output:

```py
{
'A': [2, 5, 9, 10],
'B': [1, 6, 7, 12], 
'C': [3, 4, 8, 11]
}
```